# Check new form-input against old form-input

Tags: 7, forms

I have added some extra options in the My Profile page which users can edit. But now I have to track down the change of this value...

It's a checkbox and whenever the user (un)checks this box, something must happen. So I thought this would be in the `$form_state`, but no luck there.

Next thing I did was to preform an EntityQuery on the user object and try to cross-reference it with the input, but again, no luck.

So how can I (programmatically) detect if a form-element goes from unchecked to checked or the other way around?

**EDIT:** What I try to do is an implementation with Campaign Monitor (a newsletter plugin). If a user has changed it's checkbox, his subscription must be updated (of leave it as it is when there is no change)

Comment: what changes you want to do on form element change? An overview would do.

Comment: An overview is necessary, But maybe Rules can help you a bit.

Comment: @subhojit777, does my edit make it a bit more clearer?

Comment: @Vic, what do you mean by 'overview'?

Answer (score 0):

When you change something in form, that change can be found in `$form_state`. You need to add an AJAX callback and do your changes in that callback.

Sample code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'MY_FORM_ID':
      $form['field_select']['#ajax'] = array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'your_ajax_callback',
        'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
      );
    break;
  }
}

/**
 * AJAX Callback.
 */
function your_ajax_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // dpm($form_state);
  // Check $form_state here and update subscription.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the effort. And how can I check if a value has changed? Compare `$form` and `$form_state`? Is the 'field_select' in your $form-variable, the field it applies to?

Comment: @Michiel you will get the changed value in $form_state. Inside $form_state['values']['field_select'] (I guess) you will get the changed value. I have did a dpm($form_state) inside the AJAX callback

Comment: The field is called `$form['field_newsletter']`, but any `dpm` or `die('yes')` doesn't show up, although I changed my value.  What do I do wrong?

Comment: Ok! I managed to do so, but Ajax isn't an option now I saw it working... The actions should happen invisible and not causing any loading of content... Is there an other option for adding a callback besides Ajax?

Comment: @Michiel since the dpm is in ajax callback so you have to refresh the page to see dpm results. I guess you have not refreshed the page..

Comment: @Michiel dont know.. sorry and what is the problem with ajax callback? The callback do not need to return $form. You just do your stuff and end the function.

Comment: The issue is I connect to an API and every time a user checks the checkbos, a connection to the API will be made (bandwidth) and the website will give some visual feedback while it's processing the Ajax request, and that's something I want to avoid...

Comment: I have edited the answer, see if that helps

Comment: Indeed, it hides the throbber, but that doesn't solve the issue the API is called every time the users (un)checks the checkbox. Or does it?

Comment: When you un(check) checkbox, you need that the user subscription will be updated. This is done by ajax callback, and of course API will be called every time since you want to do the updation process without page refresh. If you do not want live update then there is no need to add ajax callback. Simple form submit would do, just you need to add a custom submit handler for API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue and I haven't found any easy answer. My solution was to create a "consistency check" function triggered after editing content, which would compare the values provided in the form with how things are actually set-up. If the values were inconsistent with the set-up I would know that they were changed.

In other words, whenever you edit the profile set things up whether they were changed or not. In case of editing a profile it will not be too heavy for the web-page.